# fetch api doesn't access to nodejs + express url

Tags: node.js, fetch

i have a server.js which has listening port 4000. Please check below code

```
const port = 4000;

const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()

const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "musteri"

});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database Connected!");
});

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/user', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    con.query('select * from musteri_ayarlar', function (error, results, fields) {
        if(error) throw error;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});

app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if(err) { console.log(err) };
  console.log('Service Port ' + port + ' started')
})
```

with above code listening **localhost:4000/user**

i can access without any problem from chrome when i call **localhost:4000/user** that returns a record from mysql.

My problem started when i call **localhost:4000/user** adress from fetch api.

it saying **POST http://localhost:4000/user 404 (Not Found)**

Here is my fetch code from app.jsx

````
  componentDidMount() {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
          'Content-Type': 'applications/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username: "John", password: 30 })
    };

    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/user`, requestOptions)
    .then(handleResponse => handleResponse.text())
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        return user;

    });

  }```

What is wrong with my fetchAPI code? Thanks.
````

Comment: `app.get(...)` will only listen for GET requests, you are sending a POST request.

Comment: You don't have any route defined for post request. Define one more route `app.post('/user',function(req,res){})`;

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/user', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    con.query('select * from musteri_ayarlar', function (error, results, fields) {
        if(error) throw error;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});
```

you have made an get endpoint here to access it

Change the request method in fetch

```
 const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
          'Content-Type': 'applications/json'
        }
    };
```

GET doesn't accept any body , as you are not using the request , this will satisfy